# how to store select/option inside a foreach in a database?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a foreach for questions, inside that foreach I print the questions and below I place a select/option

```
@foreach ($questions as $index => $question)
        <p>{{$question->title}}</p>
        <p>{{$question->id}}</p>
        <select wire:model="answers" name="question" id="question">
            <option value="" selected></option>
            <option value="yes">YES</option>
            <option value="no">NO</option>
        </select>
@endforeach
```

[output foreach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA1re.png)

I am trying to save all the answers in a database table, in the select I put a `wire:model="answers"` linked to an array inside the component `public $answers=[];` to capture the answers

How can I capture all the answers of the selects, and then store all in the database?

Comment: `public answers=[];` and `wire:model="answers.{{$index}}"` it's suppose to work. Try to remove the id attribute

Comment: my bad, i remove the id atributte and it works

Answer (score 0):

got it, you need to remove any unnecessary attribute and in the select you need to pass the $index to the array `wire:model="answers.{{$index}}"`